# Зачем нужен std::binary_search, если есть std::find?

Tags: c++

Зачем нужен `std::binary_search`, если есть `std::find`?

Comment: Хотя бы тем, что один из них возвращает `bool`, а другой `iterator` + алгоритмы поиска у них разные в общем случае.

Comment: `std::binary_search` нужно использовать уже для отсортированной последовательности

Comment: @StateItPrimitive проверить find на равенство end(); всё равно сложность будет лучше

Comment: @StateItPrimitive и сортировать не надо

Comment: @nikita Дело в том, что один тебе может лишь сказать, что такой элемент имеется/не имеется, а второй может вернуть итератор на него (либо `end`), с которым ты уже можешь выполнять необходимые тебе действия.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive ну, `find` обходит по всем параметрам, для чего тогда добавили `binary_search`?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive видимо должна быть ситуация, когда нужно использовать bsearch

Comment: @nikita Я на 100% не уверен в том, что под капотом `find` какой-то единый алгоритм и все такое, но логично предположить (скорее всего перегружен для каждого контейнера + еще с учетом каких-нибудь особенностей каждого ветвится реализация мб), что на сортированном массиве с произвольным доступом к элементам (типа `std::vector`) бинарный поиск должен отработать быстрее. Т.е. find в общем случае применим для любого массива (сортированного/не сортированного), с любым типом доступа, в отличие от `binary_search`.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive `On average, logarithmic in the distance between first and last: Performs approximately log2(N)+2 element comparisons (where N is this distance).
On non-random-access iterators, the iterator advances produce themselves an additional linear complexity in N on average.`

Comment: @nikita Если вам нужны сугубые факты, то вы можете просто взять и протестировать (время выполнения поиска в упорядоченном `vector` посредсвом этих двух функций на большом количестве элементов с большим количеством итераций), увидите колосальную разницу между первым и вторым (т.е. бинарный поиск будет работать и правда с логарифмической сложностью, а отличие от полного перебора `find` в общем случае, но опять возможны ньюансы), например вот

Answer (score 15):

Бинарный поиск работает только на:

- контейнерах с произвольным доступом (например, массив)
- которые отсортированы

Это довольно жесткие требования. Если они не выполняются, остается только линейный поиск.

Скорость работы бинарного поиска - логарифмическая, линейного - сюрприз - линейная.

Это означает, например, что среди четырех миллиардов отсортированных элементов (2^32), искомый гарантированно отыщется всего за 32 шага сравнения. Или же будет показано, что такого элемента нет.

Для достижения такого же результата, линейный поиск будет выполнять все 4 миллиарда сравнений.

Comment: Тогда для чего он нужен?)

Comment: Для поиска в контейнерах, которые обладают вышеперечисленными свойствами

Comment: в них и `find` можно использовать

Comment: @nikita можно, только оно гораздо медленнее будет

Comment: @nikita линейный поиск имеет сложность O(N), а бинарный - O(logN)

Comment: @gbg, дополните ответ сложностю binary_search и find.

Comment: @nikita, если упрощенно - поиск find по массиву из миллиона элементов потребует 1000000 сравнений в худшем случае, а бинарный поиск по сортированному массиву log2(1000000) = 19.9... т.е. 20 в худшем случае. Соответственно, и скорость поиска выше. Для миллиарда элементов разница будет еще больше.

Answer (score 2):

`std::binary_search` некорректо сравнивать с `std::find`, последний скорее нужно сравнивать с `std::lower_bound`. Вкратце - `std::lower_bound` более эффективный, но имеет ограничение на последовательность, к которой может применяться. `std::find` же более общий, но менее эффективный.

Answer (score 0):

- `std::binary_search` работает за сложность `О(log2n)`, a
  `std::find` за `О(n)`.
- `std::binary_search` применяется только к
  отсортированным по неубыванию контейнерам, кроме ассоциативных
  (другими словами контейнеры, которые поддерживают итераторы
  произвольного доступа). И она возвращает

  - `true`, если элемент найден
  - `false`, если нет.